# Which XPath to identify nodes that have a common sibling?

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I have an xml file which looks like this (using R to parse the code):

```
code <- '<a>

  <b>
    <c>1</c>
    <c>2</c>
  </b>

  <b>
    <c>3</c>
    <c>4</c>
  </b>

  <c>5</c>
  <c>6</c>

  <b>
    <c>7</c>
    <c>8</c>
  </b>

  <c>9</c>
  <c>10</c>

</a>'

library(XML)
parsed <- xmlParse(code)
```

The problem that I am dealing with is that the file is partially malformed for the purposes I need it for. The correct format would require that every c node must be nested in b tags. As you can see that is true for some of the nodes, but not for the c nodes with values 5,6,9,10.

I know how to work with and edit XML nodes with the XML package. The problem I am confronted with now is that I need to address the two groups of c nodes seperately, i.e. I need to come up with an XPath expression that identifies c nodes (5,6) as one group an c nodes (9,10) as another group. A simple "//c" only identifies all the c nodes which is not what I want.

## Solution

I thought I share the solution I came up with. It start with chorobas XPath and then walks the chain of siblings to this node, checks their names und repeats this process until it hits a b node. Maybe this helps someone.

```
  node1 <- XML::getNodeSet(parsed, "/a/c[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::b]")

  if(length(node1) > 0){

    for(i in 1:length(node1)){

      node.container <- list()
      node.container[[1]] <- node1[[i]]

      gg <- 1
      repeat{
        sibling.node <- XML::getSibling(node.container[[gg]])

        if(is.null(sibling.node)) break
        if(!(XML::xmlName(sibling.node) == "c"))) break

        node.container[[gg + 1]] <- sibling.node
        gg <- gg + 1
      }

      invisible(new.b <- XML::newXMLNode("b"))
      invisible(XML::replaceNodes(oldNode = node1[[i]], newNode = new.b))
      invisible(XML::addChildren(new.b, node.container))
    }

  }
```

Comment: Such xpath return 5,6,9,10. But i don't know, how make a group :( `//c[not(ancestor::b)][following::*[1][name()='c'] or preceding::*[1][name()='c']]`

Comment: or 5,9 `//c[not(ancestor::b)][self() or following::*[1][name()='c']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can't return groups of nodes, it returns a node list. You can make it return the first of the pair easily, though:

```
/a/c[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::b]
```

(i.e. `c` under `a` whose immediately preceding sibling is a `b`),

or, if the structure is somewhere deeper

```
//c[parent::a][preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::b]
```

To get to the second node, just use `following-sibling::c[1]`.

**Note:**
 this wouldn't catch the pair of `c`s at the very beginning of `a`.

Comment: thank you. This got me on the right track. I am now using your first xpath and then retrieve all the c siblings from these nodes. And you are right, I need to make the assumption that unnested c nodes do not appear at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @crubba: You can always check for them with `//a/*[1]/self::c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the `c` nodes that are not children of `b` with

```
getNodeSet(parsed, "//c[name(parent::*)!='b']")
```

If you want those that are also followed by a `c` (the start of a pair). You can do.

```
badc <- getNodeSet(parsed, "//c[name(parent::*)!='b' and name(following-sibling::*)='c']")
```

and you can get the next in the pair with

```
xmlApply(badc, xpathSApply, "./following-sibling::c[1]")
```